CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/X/BINARYFILE":library "/data/valgrind/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so" needed or dlopened by
Executed valgrind for.so binary files in android framework. Facing linker error as mentioned below during command execution time, How to resolve this?
command: valgrind --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck /vendor/bin/BINARYFILE

=11442== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11442== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11442== Using Valgrind-3.23.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11442== Command: /vendor/bin/BINARYFILE
==11442== CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/vendor/bin/BINARYFILE": library "/data/valgrind/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so" needed or dlopened by "/vendor/bin/BINARYFILE" is not accessible for the namespace "(default)"
==11442==
==11442== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11442==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11442==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==11442==
==11442== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11442==
==11442== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==11442== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


"CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE" doesn't come from the official Valgrind source. How did you build/install Valgrind? How has it been patched for your system?

from official valgrind source,https://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html#current @PaulFloyd

OK this must be an Andoid thing.

I suggest that you open an item at https://bugs.kde.org. Run with -v -v and attach the log. I'm not aware of any Valgrind developer working on Android and we rarely get any patches for that platform so this might be difficult to fix.

And this is amd64 Android, not arm64?

Linker error is getting only vendor/bin/ partition.. not happening in system/bin partition.

I just saw this
Android linker errors
Could you try the suggestions and report back here if you get it to work?

Its working fine. Thank you for your time
